# Using to_dms function in CRS conversion expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, function, degrees-minutes-seconds

I need to create in a point layer attribute table new fields with the points coordinates converted in different geographic CRS through an expression like:

```
x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:xxxxx', 'EPSG:xxxxx'))
```

Is it possible (and how) to integrate in this expression the function `to_dms()` in order to convert directly the decimal degrees output to DMS degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a layer in OSGB coordinates (EPSG code 27700) and I can use:

```
to_dms(x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'epsg:4326')), 'x', 3)
```

to get a DMS representation of the point coordinates.

For example, I can use this expression in the labelling engine:

[image]

and my points get labelled with the DMS longitude, even though their coordinate system is still OSGB metres:

[image]

You can use that expression to add a DMS longitude column to the attribute table (and with slight modification, latitude too).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer solves the problem perfectly