# Show Running Lat/Long Coordinates in Status Bar on Bottom

Tags: qgis, coordinates

Running QGIS 3.28.2-Firenze.

How can I show running lat/long coordinates in the bottom status bar that change while I'm  moving the cursor?  Currently, it's showing Coordinate "976105,654924" as shown in pic below.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coordinates you see relate to the pointer coordinates in the project reference CRS, which are therefore not necessarily in degrees.

**Display default coordinates in degrees:**

If you change the project CRS to one in degrees, you will see Lat & Lon

[image]

**Add your own custom coordinates display:**

If you want to keep the current project CRS (not in degrees) and add a custom display in degrees, go to the following menu :

```
View/Decorations/Title Label
```

and add this custom code:

```
  [% x(transform(@canvas_cursor_point
    , 'EPSG:2154', 'EPSG:4326' ))%],[% y(transform(@canvas_cursor_point
    , 'EPSG:2154', 'EPSG:4326' ))%]
```

With your project CRS instead of `'EPSG:2154'`

[image]

It will display the cursor coordinates in degrees even if your project CRS is different:

[image]

Notes:

- coordinates update when you click on the map layout
- you can easily customize the code, to round the coordinates, display them in degrees, minutes, seconds, add the N/S or E/W indicators

Comment: Kasper, thank you very much for your answer, super helpful.  I'm new to QGIS, where can I learn how to customize the code (assume it's Python) to round, display in DMS, etc?  I tried to use excel expressions but did not work.

Comment: @MichaelLeonard, you are welcome. These are called [QGIS expressions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html). If you click on "Insert or edit and Expression" rather than just pasting the function text, the editor provides the function reference and examples. The Epsilon sign represents this in QGIS overall. Among these functions, you'll find [to_dms()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305665/using-to-dms-function-in-crs-conversion-expression-in-qgis). If you are happy with the answer, you might want to accept it by checking the mark next to it.