# Changing the live coordinate display in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

My coordinate display window in QGIS only shows long lat (minutes and degrees etc.), even though my project CRS is projected.

Does anybody know how to change it so that it displays the projected units? I just want to be able to eyeball the coordinate I am looking at.

[image]

Comment: See this answer, just donthe conversion the other way round : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448448/show-running-lat-long-coordinates-in-status-bar-on-bottom/448452#448452. Otherwise just set your project CRS to the one from your Layer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show Running Lat/Long Coordinates in Status Bar on Bottom](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448448/show-running-lat-long-coordinates-in-status-bar-on-bottom)

Comment: @nmtoken : you refer to the same link I referred to ! :)

Comment: @Kasper it comes from Review queue. not written manually.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `File > Properties > General` tab. In `Coordinate and Bearing Display`, set `Display coordinate using` to `Custom projection Units`, and `Coordinate CRS` to the CRS you want to display.

[image]